# Transfer backups or directly create backups on Amazon S3

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

I'm planning to use Amazon S3 to store our regular SQL Backups. I would like to know if it is recommended to upload the backup after locally created  or create it directly on S3. I think it could be more secure in case of a ransomware infection to upload the files instead of having an S3 bucket mapped to the server (using for example Tntdrive), but I would like to know your recommendations on this topic.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't map a drive directly to S3 if you're worried about viruses or ransomware, even though bucket versions can protect against corruption. If your backup software can create files directly in S3 using the API then yes, do that. If it can't then you'll probably have to create the file locally then upload it.

It's fairly easy to create an IAM user with permissions just to upload to one bucket, with no delete or other access. You can use commercial software or the AWS command line tools. If it would be helpful I have IAM policies and scripts I could share.

Comment: *"If your backup software can upload directly to S3 then yes, do that."* This could be misinterpreted as suggesting that backups be created as files on a "mounted" bucket, which is what I suspect is meant by "directly" in the original question due to the mention of tntdrive... and that scenario is a really bad idea for multiple reasons.  I believe your intention is to say that if the backup uilitity has the capability to speak *directly to the S3 API* then it's fine use that capability, and that should be true... but the "mounted bucket" model is not properly considered "directly to S3."

Answer (score 5):

We are using VEEAM for this purpose like described here http://veeam.com/blog/leverage-vtl-on-amazon-aws-object-storage-s3-glacier.html with StarWind VTL for AWS http://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-cloud-vtl-for-veeam.

This setup utilizes both S3 and Glacier using intelligent retention policies where you can precisely configure how long you backups remain on premise and specify the amount of time for backups go to to Glacier vault.

Obviosly you can use any backup software that supports virtual tapes. VTL format might sound weird but it actually gives two great benefits. A virtual tape being an object works great with cloud storage which is object-based too. And it's not hit by ransomware (proven with recent Petya.A pestilence).

Comment: Amazon has own VTL BTW, and that's a good option to consider. https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/vtl/ It might lack other cloud providers support, and got no Veeam integration so far but I'd add it to the short list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the dB server your self and on EC2 why not just snapshot the disk drive where you dump the dB with Amazon consistent snapshot tools. It uses the same space as it's differential and as it is at disk level doesn't have any virus paths outside the xen virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

I backup my data directly to S3 bucket using cloudberry backup tool and as the data transferred is encrypted and S3 also has its own security features, there is nothing to worry about ransomware attack on the backed up data.
Also, the cloud storage providers use redundant storage setup, hence there are multiple copies of backup data for any such DR situations.

Comment: Neither encryption nor S3's redundancy provides any protection from ransomware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems to upload the SQL backups directly to S3. Why not if you able to this. Either it via AWS CLI or third party backup applications.

Also, I guess you have EBS volumes attached to your EC2 instance. To increase IOPS for your DBs. Aren't you? If so, you can create the snapshots of your volumes. Which will be stored in S3 and incremental in nature.

As for the double durability - use AWS S3 Cross-region replication functionality.

Hope it helps you to make a decision.